# Django ModelForm with model having ForeignKey field does not display selectBox correctly

Tags: python, django, forms, foreign-keys

This is probably easy to solve. I created a form which use forms.ModelForm.
My model has ForeignKey field. Form creates a select field for foreignKey, but but does not display value correctly.

models.py

```
from django.db import models

# Create your models here.

class Gender(models.Model):

  name = models.CharField(max_length=8, null=True)

  class Meta:
    db_table='gender'

class UserExample(models.Model):

  name     = models.CharField(max_length=16,null=True)
  age      = models.IntegerField(blank=True, null=True)
  gender   = models.ForeignKey('Gender', on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True)

  class Meta:
      db_table='userExample'

  def __str__(self):
      return ""
```

forms.py

```
from django import forms

from .models import UserExample, Gender

class UserForm(forms.ModelForm):

    class Meta:
        model = UserExample
        fields = ('name', 'age', 'gender')
```

views.py

```
from django.shortcuts import render    
from .forms import UserForm

# Create your views here.

def index(request):

    form = UserForm        
    return render(
        request,
        'index.html',
        {'form': form}
    )
```

urls.py

```
from django.conf.urls import url
from . import views

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^$', views.index, name='index'),
]
```

index.html

```
<html>
    <head>
    <title>test </title>
    </head>
<body>


<form action="formreturn/" method="post">
    {{ form.as_p }}
    <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

And after I launch my app. In select box I get only selection for gender objects but not for gender names.

[image]

*Optional* I used to add values using sqllite3 like this:
sqlite> insert into gender values(1,"Male");
sqlite> insert into gender values(2,"Female");

Comment: define `__str__` returning `self.name` in `Gender` class

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Implement `__unicode__` or `__str__` method in Gender model,

```
def __unicode__(self):
    return '%s' % self.name
```

And it will display gender names in your option choices.

**How to customize the default form field behavior of ForeignKey Model field**

ForeignKey maps to ModelChoiceField and you can override the default behavior of the same. You can override the 'Select' option field value using 'to_field_name' parameter (useful when you have multiple unique fields in your related model) otherwise option field values are defaulted to pk field.

'empty_label' will change the default "--------" with the empty_label atrribute

forms.py

```
class UserForm(forms.ModelForm):
    gender = forms.ModelChoiceField(queryset=Gender.objects.all(),
                                    to_field_name = 'name',
                                    empty_label="Select Gender")

    class Meta:
        model = UserExample
        fields = ('name', 'age', 'gender')
```

Option display names are defaulted to `__str__` method output. You can override the default behavior by writing a custom choice field class (inherited from ModelChoiceField) and override the label_from_instance() method.

Answer (score 1):

```
def__str__(self):
      return self.name
```

You will add this on your gender class

Answer (score 0):

I already gave this answer in another place, hope it's not bad to copy paste.
In my case, I didn't wanna go make an **str** for my billion models, so I just did this:

You can make one custom ModelChoiceField to which you can pass a function. That way if you have different fields for which you want different attributes to be displayed, you can have only 1 class:

```
class CustomModelChoiceField(forms.ModelChoiceField):
name_function = staticmethod(lambda obj: obj)

def __init__(self, name_function, *args, **kwargs):
    if not name_function is None: self.name_function = name_function
    super(CustomModelChoiceField, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

def label_from_instance(self, obj):
     return self.name_function(obj);
```

You can then call it as simply as this:

```
form_field = CustomModelChoiceField(
    lambda obj: obj.get_full_name(),
    queryset=Whatever.objects.all(),
)
```

You can also pass None in case you're doing some dynamic stuff and it'll just basically default to a regular ModelChoiceField. I'm not too much of a python guy  but this works for me.